# JQuery Validation event setting

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I set up my validator so it will check all fields on the form whenever changes the value of any input on this form. I've tried

```
$("#form-user-edit").validate({
        keypress : true
    });
```

but it's not working.

I've made a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NickBunich/pDrTF/1/

The problem is that when u type something in first input - other inputs become enabled, but if u then type something in second input, then erase it and then erase text in first input - error message and highlight will stay.

Comment: where is the validation rules?

Comment: It is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dCJc7/ the validation rules are passed as attributes like `minlength`, `required` etc to the input fields

Comment: I've edited my post and there is now a link to the fiddle.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the disabled state of the controls

Comment: It's not working because there is no such option as `keypress:` within the `.validate()` plugin.  Modify the `onkeyup:` callback option instead.

Comment: this function helped me    function listenModelChangeToRevalidateDocument() {
 userModel.societyOfAppraisers.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  isDocumentValid();
 });
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer demonstrates the proper usage of [the built-in callback event functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) of the plugin.  The creation of external callback functions is superfluous and unnecessary.

---

Your code...

```
$("#form-user-edit").validate({
    keypress : true
});
```

You cannot simply "make-up" or "invent" `.validate()` options.  `keypress:` does not exist. See [this page for the *only* available options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

> How can I set up my validator so it will check all fields on the form
>   whenever changes the value of any input on this form.

There is already an option called `onkeyup` and it's turned on by default.  (This checks only the active input on every key-up event.)

You could modify `onkeyup` to suit your needs.  This will check the *entire* form on *every* key-up event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form-user-edit").validate({
        // other rules and options,
        onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === '') {
                return;
            } else if (element.name in this.submitted || element === this.lastActive) {
                if($("#form-user-edit").valid()) {
                    $("#form-user-edit .error").removeClass('error');
                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CMT5r/

Working demo contains the OP's code modified to function as requested.

Comment: still not working, if you enter an text in the first text box -> this will enable and mark the next two fields as required, then clear the text in the first text box then the next two text boxes will be disabled but the red highlight box around the text boxes is not getting cleared.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, thanks for pointing that out.  I've fixed my answer so that it now functions as requested.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, it's certainly not the same since mine is using the plugin's built-in `onkeyup` event handler... yours is an external `change` event handler running in parallel with the plugin's handler function.

Comment: you are right about the validation initialization portion, but about the `error` class not being there after `valid()` call you were wrong

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I was only wrong because I failed to notice the OP is using custom `highlight` & `unhighlight` functions that apply this custom `error` class instead of using the built-in error class.  (And I removed my comments and my down-vote from your answer.)  However, I still think it's best to use the built-in event callback functions for this plugin rather than simply creating new ones.  IMO, it's less overhead and better practice.

Comment: yes, you are right about that, in terms of overhead your method will force the validation every time a key is pressed, isn't it?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Validation every time a key is pressed and on focus out is how the plugin already operates *by default*.  I did not _add_ the `onkeyup:` event, I only changed its default callback behavior.  It's exactly how [the demo in your own answer](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pDrTF/6/) is set to operate, except that, on top of the default plugin events, [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pDrTF/6/) additionally has it's own external `change` event which **also** fires every time a value is changed (*the value constantly changes on key press and focus out*).  Get it now?

Answer (score 1):

As an Example ,you have to :

- specify rules for check

  ```
   $("#form-user-edit").validate({
         rules: {
           name: "required",
           email: {
             required: true,
             email: true
           }
         },
         messages: {
           name: "Please specify your name",
           email: {
             required: "We need your email address to contact you",
             email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
           }
         }
      })
  ```

this tutorial would give you vast explaination on the validations [see here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `change` event handler to do this

```
$("#form-user-edit").on('change', ':input', function(){
    if($("#form-user-edit").valid()) {
        $("#form-user-edit .error").removeClass('error')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pDrTF/6/)

Comment: that's better. but still there is a red highlighting around the inputs and font color stays red.

Comment: it is because those fields are disabled by the time the change event is fired, validator ignores fields that are `:submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]`

Comment: It's very dirty since the plugin already has built-in event handlers for all of this.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!---------------------- Personal Details -------------------------->
<div class="inputchanges">
    <form>
        <fieldset id="personalDetailsForm">
            <div class="border rounded shadow">
                <div class="bg-primary text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-top">
                    <h3>Personal Details / ವೈಯಕ್ತಿಕ ವಿವರಗಳು</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="border rounded p-3">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="name" class="col-form-label">
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <div class="mr-2" style="align-self: self-start;">3.</div>
                                    <div>
                                        Candidate Full Name : <i class="invalid">*</i><br>
                                        <span class="av-font-kn">C¨sÀåyðAiÀÄ ¥ÀÆtð ºÉ¸ÀgÀÄ :</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Candidate Name / ಅರ್ಜಿದಾರರ ಹೆಸರು" id="name"
                                class="form-control" minlength="1" maxlength="60" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]{1,60}" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="fname" class="col-form-label">
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <div class="mr-2" style="align-self: self-start;">4.</div>
                                    <div>
                                        Father's Name : <i class="invalid">*</i><br>
                                        <span class="av-font-kn">vÀAzÉAiÀÄ ºÉ¸ÀgÀÄ :</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Father's Name / ತಂದೆಯ ಹೆಸರು" id="fname" class="form-control"
                                minlength="1" maxlength="60" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]{1,60}" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Edit</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```